# Writing a Formula to calculate 'time difference.'

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have 'Departure times' that look like this 08/04/20 00:01 Z (that is Zulu time in one cell) of my spreadsheet , and 'Arrival times' that look like this 08/04/20 00:29 Z (again, Zulu time, in one cell).  How do I write a formula that calculate the 'time difference?'

Answer (score 0):

Simply subtract each cell using time format for all cells.  Is your next question how to convert text to time number in time format? Or does that lead you to what you want?

Answer (score 0):

I will advise that you don't put/type the Z when entering you data. But format the cells to use this format: `mm/dd/yy hh:mm "Z"` or `mm/dd/yy HH:mm "Z"` if you are going to use 0-23 hours. When you enter for example, 08/04/20 00:01, the Z will appear automatically. Then use the formula `=A2-A1` to get the time difference.

EDIT: Based on the comments, you will need a formula that remove the Z part of the time. An alternative to what @FlexYourData posted is:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A3," Z","")
```

Use it on an helper column, then subtract the cells.
[image: IMG:]

If a helper column is not an option, then combine the formula as below. Format the result cell(s) as `[h]:mm` or `hh:mm`.

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A4," Z","") - SUBSTITUTE(A3," Z","")
```

Comment: The problem is that the data is an export (dump) from a program.  The "Z" is part of it, and denotes Zulu time.  Before I sent the question, I tried to remove the "Z" , and it automatically converted to "AM".

Comment: @GuestforToday See edit.

Answer (score 0):

First, remove the Z and trailing space.

```
=LEFT(A1,14)
```

Now you can use math on the values. If you subtract one from the other and make sure the cell format is in 24-hour time:

[image]

Note that this will not work so well if the source data are on different days and you will need to expand the calculation for such differences.

Comment: The problem is that the data is an export (dump) from a program.  The "Z" is part of it, and denotes Zulu time.  Before I sent the question, I tried to remove the "Z" , and it automatically converted to "AM".

Answer (score 0):

```
=LEFT(B2,LEN(B2)-2)-LEFT(A2,LEN(A2)-2)
```

Custom format the result cell (`C2`) as `[hh]:mm`

[image]